# Car model falling through the plane in ARKit plane detection

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit

I'm trying to make a simple drivable car using ARKit. I have found two ways to detect the plane. My first approach is this  here in didUpdate delegate method I just take the existing anchor and plane node and update its position and length value. When I run the app the vehicle falls through the ground and attaches itself upside down to the plane.

```
//MARK: - PLANE DETECTION
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else{return }
        self.createPlane(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node)
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
      
       
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else{return }
    
        self.updatePlane(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node)
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRemove node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        node.enumerateChildNodes { childNode, _ in
            childNode.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
    
    func createPlane(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor,node: SCNNode){
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        planeGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490451, green: 0, blue: 0.2313725501, alpha: 0.6990376656)
        planeGeometry.materials.first?.isDoubleSided = true
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: anchor.center.x, y: anchor.center.y, z: anchor.center.z)
        planeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: Float(Double.pi) / 2, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
        planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)
        planeNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        // Apply engine force to front wheels
        self.physicsVehicle.applyEngineForce(CGFloat(self.engineForce), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.applyEngineForce(CGFloat(self.engineForce), forWheelAt: 1)
        
        //Apply brake force to rear wheels
        self.physicsVehicle.applyBrakingForce(CGFloat(self.brakingForce), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.applyBrakingForce(CGFloat(self.brakingForce), forWheelAt: 1)
        
        //Add Steering value
        self.physicsVehicle.setSteeringAngle(CGFloat(self.steeringValue), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.setSteeringAngle(CGFloat(self.steeringValue), forWheelAt: 1)
    }
    
    func updatePlane(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor,node: SCNNode){
        if let planeNode = node.childNodes.first{
            if let planeGeometry = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane{
                planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
                planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)
                planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: anchor.center.x, y: anchor.center.y, z: anchor.center.z)
                print(planeNode.physicsBody)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my second approach.

Here I instead of updating the existing anchor and node I completely remove them and add a new plane. Now when I run the app it works as intended.

```
//MARK: - PLANE DETECTION
extension ViewController: ARSCNViewDelegate{
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else{return }
        self.createPlane(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node)
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didUpdate node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
      
        node.enumerateChildNodes { childNode, _ in
            childNode.removeFromParentNode()
        }
        guard let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor else{return }
    
        self.createPlane(anchor: planeAnchor, node: node)
    }
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didRemove node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
        node.enumerateChildNodes { childNode, _ in
            childNode.removeFromParentNode()
        }
    }
    
    func createPlane(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor,node: SCNNode){
        let planeGeometry = SCNPlane(width: CGFloat(anchor.extent.x), height: CGFloat(anchor.extent.z))
        planeGeometry.materials.first?.diffuse.contents = #colorLiteral(red: 0.5725490451, green: 0, blue: 0.2313725501, alpha: 0.6990376656)
        planeGeometry.materials.first?.isDoubleSided = true
        let planeNode = SCNNode(geometry: planeGeometry)
        planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: anchor.center.x, y: anchor.center.y, z: anchor.center.z)
        planeNode.eulerAngles = SCNVector3(x: Float(Double.pi) / 2, y: 0.0, z: 0.0)
        planeNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .static, shape: nil)
        planeNode.physicsBody?.isAffectedByGravity = false
        node.addChildNode(planeNode)
    }
    
    func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didSimulatePhysicsAtTime time: TimeInterval) {
        // Apply engine force to front wheels
        self.physicsVehicle.applyEngineForce(CGFloat(self.engineForce), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.applyEngineForce(CGFloat(self.engineForce), forWheelAt: 1)
        
        //Apply brake force to rear wheels
        self.physicsVehicle.applyBrakingForce(CGFloat(self.brakingForce), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.applyBrakingForce(CGFloat(self.brakingForce), forWheelAt: 1)
        
        //Add Steering value
        self.physicsVehicle.setSteeringAngle(CGFloat(self.steeringValue), forWheelAt: 0)
        self.physicsVehicle.setSteeringAngle(CGFloat(self.steeringValue), forWheelAt: 1)
    }
    
    func updatePlane(anchor: ARPlaneAnchor,node: SCNNode){
        if let planeNode = node.childNodes.first{
            if let planeGeometry = planeNode.geometry as? SCNPlane{
                planeGeometry.width = CGFloat(anchor.extent.x)
                planeGeometry.height = CGFloat(anchor.extent.z)
                planeNode.position = SCNVector3(x: anchor.center.x, y: anchor.center.y, z: anchor.center.z)
                print(planeNode.physicsBody)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I tested those two methods by falling cubes using ray cast they both work exactly same. But when I use this  car model  it falls through the floor and attaches downwards to the plane. What is the difference between those two methods which one should I need to use. Is it because of the [car model](https://file.io/4magtJHrRUcA).

Comment: It might be a positioning issue with the wheels. I noticed similar problems once with another Car Model I set-up. Finally I re-created the whole stuff in Blender exactly like the Apple Racing Car from its demo-project. then it worked.

Comment: @ZAY Yeah I also think that the problem is with car model. What is the difference between the above two different ways to detect planes. Because both of them gives same output. Which one should I prefer. Remove the existing nodes and anchor completely and add new anchor and nodes or update the existing nodes and anchor

Comment: Hard to tell regarding the floor issue. It depends on what you want. I usually do not work with updating Nodes (because I do not use them.) Normally I want to detect the floor, then I place a really large floor (you can also make an invisible floor) that stays permanent. Pay attention to the Physics configuraiton, so that it will collide with the dynamic car model. Also make sure, you make the floor a type concavePolyhedron. Regarding the car. Try to organize the wheels exactly like in the Apple-Demo project using locater nodes. Apply all location and scale transforms and export to a DAE file.